Influx micrometer config for spring kafka using xml in non spring boot app
I am using below spring integration kafka. I see lot of JMX metrics using jconsole for producer servers.
    kafka-template="kafkaTemplate" id="kafkaOutboundChannelAdapter" 
    topic="learning-topic" channel="KafkaAdapterChan" 
    send-failure-channel="FailureChan">
</int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter>

<bean id="kafkaTemplate" class="org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory">
            <constructor-arg>
                <map>
                    <entry key="bootstrap.servers" value="xyz:9092" />
                    ... <!-- more producer properties -->
                </map>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean> 

When I use spring boot producer, I see all of them are by default available in micrometer registry in influxDB, these are not enabled by default and tried creating influx beans using below
<bean id="customInfluxConfigs" class ="CustomImplemtation">
-- all the properties
</bean>

<bean id="influxRegistry> class="io.micrometer.influx.InfluxRegistry>
<constructor-arg name="config" ref="customInfluxConfigs">
<constructor-arg name="clock" ref="micrometerClock">
</bean>

However this does not publish the default jmx metrics available. Looking for help to publish the JMX metrics to influxDB using micrometer for using them in grafana.

private DefaultKafkaProducerFactory defaultProducerFactory;
private InfluxMeterRegistry influxMeterRegistry;

@Override
public void start(){
defaultProducerFactory.createProducer();
defaultProducerFactory.addListener(new MicrometerProducerListener(influxMeterRegistry))
}


See MicrometerProducerListener to be set on that DefaultKafkaProducerFactory

Thanks @Artem Bilan. I tried that, by trying to set defaultKafkaProducerFactory.addListeners(new MicrometerProducerListener(influxMeterRegistry). However it doesn't work. Metermap in meterregistry(in debug mode) is 0 and publishes nothing

Right. So, you probably still need to configure MeterRegistry some way to inject your influxRegistry.

MeterRegistry is configured and inject to implementation of SmartLifeCycle as updated in above code

I'm not sure why you call there createProducer(), but that addListener() has to be done in the afterPropertiesSet(). The start()  might be too late and Producer is created for channel adapter and cached before you try to customize it with that MicrometerProducerListener

@ArtemBilan, thanks it worked finally by setting it earlier as you adviced. But it shows only producer-metrics but not other producer-topic-metrics, is there any further configuration to get producer-topic-metrics or producer-node-metrics? Thanks

Sorry, I'm not familiar with that stuff. Might worth to raise a new SO thread with more details.
